# When building with -buildmode=c-shared I do not get the h file

Tags: go

I want to use the function `langDetectFunct` in a C++ code.
The code is taken from here: https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua-go?tab=readme-ov-file#91-basic-usage

`basic.go` :

```
package main

import "C"

import (
    "github.com/pemistahl/lingua-go"
)

// export LangDetectFunct
func LangDetectFunct(text string) (lingua.Language) {


    detector := lingua.NewLanguageDetectorBuilder().
        FromAllLanguages().
        Build()

    if language, exists := detector.DetectLanguageOf("languages are awesome"); exists {
        return language
    }
    return lingua.English
}

func main() {}
```

But I do not get the `h` file, as I should : https://github.com/vladimirvivien/go-cshared-examples

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ go build -o basic.so -buildmode=c-shared basic.go

raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ ls -lah
drwxrwxr-x   3 raphy raphy 4,0K feb 20 19:37 .
drwxr-x--- 110 raphy raphy 4,0K feb 20 17:18 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 raphy raphy  403 feb 20 19:34 basic.go
-rw-rw-r--   1 raphy raphy 5,9M feb 20 19:37 basic.so
-rw-rw-r--   1 raphy raphy  340 feb 20 19:23 go.mod
-rw-rw-r--   1 raphy raphy 1,4K feb 20 15:11 go.sum
-rw-rw-r--   1 raphy raphy  636 feb 20 17:23 main.go
```

But executing `go tool cgo basic.go` I get as output a folder with `c` and `h` files:

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ go tool cgo basic.go
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect/_obj$ ls -lah
total 32K
drwxrwxr-x 2 raphy raphy 4,0K feb 20 20:48 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 raphy raphy 4,0K feb 20 20:48 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy  581 feb 20 20:48 basic.cgo1.go
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy 1,9K feb 20 20:48 basic.cgo2.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy  564 feb 20 20:48 _cgo_export.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy 1,6K feb 20 20:48 _cgo_export.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy    0 feb 20 20:48 _cgo_flags
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy  716 feb 20 20:48 _cgo_gotypes.go
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy  611 feb 20 20:48 _cgo_main.c
```

Update 1)

If  in `basic.go` I add this simple function `Add(a, b int) int` :

```
package main

import "C"

import (
        "github.com/pemistahl/lingua-go"
)

var lan lingua.Language

// export LangDetectFunct
func Langdetectfunct(text string) lingua.Language {

    detector := lingua.NewLanguageDetectorBuilder().
        FromAllLanguages().
        Build()

    if language, exists := detector.DetectLanguageOf(text); exists {
        lan = language
    }
    lan = lingua.English

    return lan

}

//export Add
func Add(a, b int) int {
        return a + b
}

func main() {}
```

This time building with `c-shared` buildmode yields to both `basic.so`  and `basic.h` files .
But both `basic.h` and `basic.so` contain only the `Add`  function and not the `Langdetectfunct` function :
`basic.h` :

```
/* Code generated by cmd/cgo; DO NOT EDIT. */

/* package command-line-arguments */


#line 1 "cgo-builtin-export-prolog"

#include <stddef.h>

#ifndef GO_CGO_EXPORT_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_EXPORT_PROLOGUE_H

#ifndef GO_CGO_GOSTRING_TYPEDEF
typedef struct { const char *p; ptrdiff_t n; } _GoString_;
#endif

#endif

/* Start of preamble from import "C" comments.  */




/* End of preamble from import "C" comments.  */


/* Start of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */
#line 1 "cgo-gcc-export-header-prolog"

#ifndef GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H

typedef signed char GoInt8;
typedef unsigned char GoUint8;
typedef short GoInt16;
typedef unsigned short GoUint16;
typedef int GoInt32;
typedef unsigned int GoUint32;
typedef long long GoInt64;
typedef unsigned long long GoUint64;
typedef GoInt64 GoInt;
typedef GoUint64 GoUint;
typedef size_t GoUintptr;
typedef float GoFloat32;
typedef double GoFloat64;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <complex.h>
typedef _Fcomplex GoComplex64;
typedef _Dcomplex GoComplex128;
#else
typedef float _Complex GoComplex64;
typedef double _Complex GoComplex128;
#endif

/*
  static assertion to make sure the file is being used on architecture
  at least with matching size of GoInt.
*/
typedef char _check_for_64_bit_pointer_matching_GoInt[sizeof(void*)==64/8 ? 1:-1];

#ifndef GO_CGO_GOSTRING_TYPEDEF
typedef _GoString_ GoString;
#endif
typedef void *GoMap;
typedef void *GoChan;
typedef struct { void *t; void *v; } GoInterface;
typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;

#endif

/* End of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern GoInt Add(GoInt a, GoInt b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`basic.so` :

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ file basic.so
basic.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=4983baaa3ac499ac6c267a6f5a82103d6a57abcc, with debug_info, not stripped


raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ nm basic.so | grep -e "T Add" -e "T Langdetectfunct"
000000000020ef80 T Add
```

Update 2)

With :

```
//export Langdetectfunct
func Langdetectfunct(text string) lingua.Language {
```

I now get this new error message:

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ go build -o basic.so -buildmode=c- shared basic.go
# command-line-arguments
./basic.go:14:35: Go type not supported in export: lingua.Language
```

But, I guess, since it is a very different kind of issue, I should open a new StackOverflow's post.

Why does this happen? How to correctly generate `h` file and `so` file containing the `Langdetectfunct` function?

Answer (score 0):

A comment must be added before function and the function must be public - the name must start with capital letter

The linked page says:

> Use the //export comment to annotate functions you wish to make accessible to other languages.

```
// export LangDetectFunct
func LangDetectFunct(text string) (lingua.Language) {
```

See [CGO](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#hdr-C_references_to_Go)public

Comment: Hi! @Grzegorz . Thank you for helping. I added the `// export langDetectFunct
func langDetectFunct(text string) (lingua.Language) {
` , and then built again: `raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ go build -o basic.so -buildmode=c-shared basic.go` , but unfortunately I still get as output only `basic.so` and not also the `h` file

Comment: @Raphael10 And it must start with capital letter.

Comment: that was an error. Thank you. But after correcting it, I still get as output only basic.so and not also the h file : // export LangDetectFunct func LangDetectFunct(text string) (lingua.Language) { . Executing go tool cgo basic.go I get as output a folder with c and h files. I updated my post above with the content of this folder

Comment: I wrote in the post above Update 1) because I discovered that if I add in the previous `basic.go` code a simple `Add` function, the `h` file is generated, but both `h` file and `so` file contain only this `Add` function and `not` the `Langdetectfunct`. Why does this happen?

Comment: With `//export Langdetectfunct
func Langdetectfunct(text string) lingua.Language {` I now get this new, different, error : `Go type not supported in export: lingua.Language` . I updated my post above with `Update 2`

Comment: @Raphael10 This is getting off the initial topic. A new question would be better.